# multi-dimensional Sparse Matrix Compression

Tags: c++, c, indexing

Can anybody suggest a good C++ library for storing Multi-dimensional Sparse Matrix that focuses on the compression of data in matrix. The number of dimensions of the matrix will be huge (say, 80 dimensions). Any help is most welcome :).

EDIT:
The matrix is highly sparse, in the order of 0.0000001 (or) 1x10<sup>-6</sup>.

Comment: See [Recommendations for a usable, fast C++ matrix library?](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/351)

Comment: @Peter That question is explicitly tagged `linear-algebra`, and nothing in the answers there even mentions multidimensional sparse structures.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413732/looking-for-a-c-c-interface-for-efficient-computation-of-huge-sparse-matrix-in?rq=1

Comment: Yes. They are very good if my intention is to do Linear Algebra operations. But my concern is related to efficient storage and retrieval for humongous matrix data. This is the problem of indexing.

Comment: @Prabhakaran if you need just multidimensional sparse array, why don't you want to use {map|unordered_map}?

Comment: @Kassak: Let's say i have Matrix with number of dimensions as 80. When i try to store a value in the map, the key would be a structure containing a value for each dimension. So for storing a single int, the overhead is 80 ints, which makes it impossible to go for map.

Comment: @Prabhakaran I think that is required info for storage, even BUB-trees will have to store such indices.  Do you have some dimensional limitations? Are you able to decrese number of dimensions by PCA or ICA?

Comment: @kassak : PCA and related statistical methods cannot be used as they are generally not computable(like finding mean, SD). I can go for trees though, but the index data overhead is too much. Any other better ways to do this?

Comment: @Prabhakaran I guess, no, that is valuable overhead. Maybe you can perform some domain specific improvements? What are you trying to do?

Comment: 80 dimensions...mind blowing!  Suppose each dimension is indexed by either of 2 values (call them 0 and 1); you've got 2^80 cells.  You definitely need the matrix to be sparse.  What sort of data would you be processing with 80 dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

In c# I have used key value pairs or "dictionaries" to store sparse populated arrays. I think for 80 dimensions you would have to construct a string based key. Use a single function to create the key it should all remain consistent. Simply concatenate a comma separated list of the dimensions. Unfortunately I'm not aware of a good key pair, dictionary library for c++. Possibly STL if you have used it before but I would not recommend it otherwise.

Comment: Its very good approach to have the comma separated dimensions as keys. I have further improvement to this approach. Why don't I compute the hash value of the whole key string and use it as key?. Any pitfalls with this approach?

Comment: I think the collision will be the problem with storing the hash value rather than whole key string.